# Shift columns UP if matching text found in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataset, apply

I want to remove certain values in columns in a data frame, but I'm stuck. I am trying to use *apply* function on my dataset by columns (margin = 2) and I am trying the following function but it yield an error:

```
dataset = apply(dataset, MARGIN = 2, function(dataset) dataset[-"Matching_text"])
```

> Error in -"Matching_text" : invalid argument to unary operator

My question is how to shift the column up when finding certain text?

Really thanks for your kind reply.

**MRE**

```
dataset <- mtcars
dataset = apply(dataset, MARGIN = 2, function(dataset) dataset[-3.07])
```

#There are three 3.07 values in **drat** column and I want them to be removed so this column should be 3 cells shorter and replace them with NAs in the end.
Instead an error is thrown

> Error in -"3.07" : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: I created MRE, thank you.

Comment: @RonakShah thank you for your answer. I need to remove them completely, so for example if x <- 1:10 and I want to exclude 1, the vector should be x<- 2:10 or x<- 2:10, NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a dataframe back you can use -

```
dataset[] <- lapply(dataset, function(x) x[x != 3.07][seq_along(x)])
dataset

#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 2.93 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.00 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.23 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 4.08 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 4.93 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 4.22 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 3.70 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 2.76 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 3.15 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.73 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 3.08 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 4.08 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 4.43 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.77 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.22 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 3.62 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.54 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.11 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175   NA 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335   NA 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109   NA 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

and the same with `apply` -

```
dataset[] <- apply(dataset, 2, function(x) x[x != 3.07][seq_along(x)])
```

---

To get a list output without appending `NA`'s you can do -

```
dataset <- lapply(dataset, function(x) x[x != 3.07])
```

Comment: Exactly that one I wanted. Thank you! I didn't know about seq_along

Comment: One more bonus question: If I want to remove the previous and the next one from the column, what is the way?

Comment: That would require a different approach. Can you ask that as a new question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `replace`

```
transform(
  dataset,
  drat = replace(drat, drat==3.07,NA)
)
```